# U&L swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 1750 reputation (as of Mar 2) and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Unix & Linux Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Unix & Linux Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: unix.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: unix.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show/products/stack-exchange-sharpie), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store as soon as we're able)</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!!

Comment: Is the SE sharpie supposed to say in the description "Get your **Super User** Sharpie today"?

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much! Unix SE is a great community to be a part of.

Comment: I'm guessing by these measures, Gilles is already on the way to an around-the-world cruise...

Comment: +1 to @MaxMackie. Now if I only had time to answer more...

Comment: Thank you very much ^^

Comment: Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Weird someone downvoted this offer.

Comment: Look forward to it. Thank you!

Comment: @tshepang maybe they just missed the second page.

Comment: Have you got a snapshot of the first two pages? Not sure if was already there on 2nd of march...

Comment: :) Thanks! Long Live UNIX

Comment: @nils - you should have got an email if you were.

Comment: @ChrisDown not sure - there are MANY mail-filters between my e-mail and the internet. Mail is not guaranteed to arrive, too.

Comment: What rock was I living under when this offer came out? :(

Comment: how to get unix stackexchange tshirt again?

Answer (score 2):

T-Shirt, stickers and pens arrived today (Germany). Thank you very much. :)